# Rails - create a user, then find the next available record from another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have my /lead/new action working fine. Since the person is signing up for a contest, I need to get the next available ticket number from my Ticket model (which I imported from a CSV), which has a foreign key for lead_id.

I also need to add the lead_id to the Ticket.lead_id column after @lead.save = true. Can someone provide guidance? I'm a newb and after watching videos about nested resources, I'm more confused.

```
 def create
    @lead = Lead.new(lead_params)
    if @lead.save
      redirect_to @lead 
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end
```

My model columns below for the models in question.

```
Ticket.column_names 
 => ["id", "code", "created_at", "updated_at", "lead_id"] 


Lead.column_names  
 => ["id", "name", "email", "created_at", "updated_at"]
```

Thank you!

UPDATE - Lead.rb

```
class Lead < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :tickets

    after_create :assign_ticket

def assign_ticket
  Lead.tickets << Ticket.where(lead_id: nil).first
end

end
```

Now the problem is when I create a new Lead:

```
NoMethodError in LeadsController#create

Extracted source 


def assign_ticket
  Lead.tickets << Ticket.where(lead_id: nil).first  #this is the error line
end
```

end

Update #2 - now works

```
class Lead < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :tickets

    after_create :assign_ticket

    def assign_ticket
      self.tickets << Ticket.where(lead_id: nil).first
    end

end
```

When I create the Lead it does indeed assign it the 1st untaken ticket. Now, after Lead create action, how can I print the ticket?

Comment: What is 'next available ticket'? Last by created_at? Could you attach code from both models?

Comment: well, it's the next ticket based on no Lead having claimed it yet.

Comment: Just iterate through tickets in your view and print it. `@lead.tickets.each do |ticket| ...`

Comment: got it - thanks again @AleksandrK.  Real quick self.tickets << Ticket.where(lead: nil).first   what is this assignment actually doing? It works, it's appending a Ticket record, where lead_id does not exist, to the Lead (self)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define associations in models like:

**Ticket.rb**

```
belongs_to :lead
```

**Lead.rb**

```
has_many :tickets
```

Then in model **Lead.rb** write:

```
after_create :assign_ticket

def assign_ticket
  self.tickets << Ticket.where(lead: nil).first
end
```

Comment: NoMethodError in LeadsController#create
undefined method `tickets' for #<Class:0x007ffe1c74e510>

Extracted source (around line #7):

def assign_ticket
  Lead.tickets << Ticket.where(lead: nil).first
end

end

Comment: Not in controller, in model. `/app/models/lead.rb`

Comment: @jrjames83 I've updatet my answer, `self.tickets` or `@lead.tickets` if you in controller instead of `Lead.tickets`